# get an undifined $scope in angularJS using api

Tags: angularjs

I'm new in angularJS and I got a small problem which is : 
(i'll explain some details)
I have a SQL database which is deployed in Azure and I get the data from web services.

when I want to retrieve data from the database and expose it in the view , it works.

this is the controller :

```
    var app = angular.module('ngdemoApp.controllers', []);    
app.controller('CustomerViewCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'ShowCustomerFactory','LikeProfilCustomerFactory','ShowManagerFactory',
                                function ($scope, $routeParams, ShowCustomerFactory,LikeProfilCustomerFactory,ShowManagerFactory) {
                                $scope.incrementLikeProfil = function (id) {                        LikeProfilCustomerFactory.likeProfil({id:$scope.customer.Id});
                                        $scope.customer = ShowCustomerFactory.show({id: $routeParams.id});
                                    }

                                    $scope.customer = ShowCustomerFactory.show({id: $routeParams.id});      
                                }]);
```

notice that the customer is in the database so it has properties in other word if I do `{{customer.Id}}` this expression shows me the value in the view.

However, when I want to use the `$scope.customer` in the controller like this

```
app.controller('CustomerViewCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'ShowCustomerFactory','LikeProfilCustomerFactory','ShowManagerFactory',
                                function ($scope, $routeParams, ShowCustomerFactory,LikeProfilCustomerFactory,ShowManagerFactory) {


                                    $scope.incrementLikeProfil = function (id) {

                                        LikeProfilCustomerFactory.likeProfil({id:$scope.customer.Id});
                                        $scope.customer = ShowCustomerFactory.show({id: $routeParams.id});
                                    }

                                    $scope.customer = ShowCustomerFactory.show({id: $routeParams.id});  

                                    $scope.test = $scope.customer.Id;

                                }]);
```

the `$scope.test` cannot be filled by `$scope.customer.Id`, at the same time the `$scope.customer` is filled and the view can display the value of customer but when I want to display the `$scope.test` in the view, i didn't get any responce.

Is there any solution ? Thank you

Comment: we have no idea what you're talking about. Give us the code where the error comes from

Comment: Please don't post your question until you have included all the details we will need to solve your problem. This question currently lacks all such details, and has no actual question yet.

Comment: is it ok now  ? i think it's clear now , i need helps soon  because i've to complete my project before wednesday

Comment: Could you show us the code of `ShowCustomerFactory.show` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$scope.customer = ShowCustomerFactory.show({id: $routeParams.id});
```

If the above statement is making a service request and fetching data from server. This will be async and won't be available.

But in the next statement itself, you are setting

```
$scope.test = $scope.customer.Id;
```

At this point of time, `$scope.customer` may be undefined. That's why you're not getting the value.

You must put this statement in the `then()` function of promise `$scope.test = $scope.customer.Id;`

So in your service, return promise using `$http` or `$q`. And in your controller:

```
  ShowCustomerFactory.show({id: $routeParams.id}).then(function(data) {
           $scope.customer = data;
           $scope.test = $scope.customer.id;
  });
```

Another workaround would be :

Initially set

```
$scope.customer = {};
```

Comment: `$scope.customer = {};` would still give undefined for `id`, so is not a answer. I'd limit the answer to using `then()`

Comment: Yes, initially it will be undefined. But once the customer object gets the data from service, it will have data.

Comment: in fact i didn't know where i'll use then()

Comment: convert `show` method in service to return promise. in your controller, you need to use then. Updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

Also here is my service I use $resource :

```
services.factory('ShowCustomerFactory', function ($resource) {
    return $resource(url + '/customerService/getCustomer?id=:id', {}, {
        show: { method: 'GET',params: {id: '@id'} }
    });
});
```